# Kafka console producer losing messages

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, bigdata

I am using the below kafka console producer command to pass the contents of the file into the kafka producer.

```
sh ~/KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list xxx:9092,yyy:9092,zzz:9092 --topic HistLoad --new-producer < data.csv
```

The Data.csv file has about 700,000 records. I receive only about 699,800 messages at the consumer output.

I checked the offset counter for consumer and based on the offset values its having only 699,800 messages in the queue.

Could you help me in finidng out what is causing this issue of losing messages. What all do i need to check to get  the root cause.

Comment: How many lines are data.csv? In my experience, Kafka will interpret each line as a new message. Are you expecting 700,000 or ~700,000?

Comment: @pjames there are about 700,000 messages i.e each line in the file is a message

Answer (score 2):

This is because the console producer has acks=0 by default. Set request-required-acks to 1 and it should be fine.

For your reference https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/KAFKA-3129

Comment: Default value for request-required-acks is 1